# OpenLayers OverviewMap not working

Tags: openlayers, map-overviews

I'm using Openlayers 4.6 API and the overviewMap function is not working. 
I'm using Bingmap areial as basemap.

```
  this.map = new ol.Map
  ({
      controls: [new ol.control.OverviewMap()],  //, attr
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults
      ({
          doubleClickZoom: false
      }),
      layers: [Bing_layer],
      target: 'map',
      view: view
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Problem might be view or bing_layer, I changed two of them, it worked here https://jsfiddle.net/omurbilgili/eyytw0gc/122/

Comment: @ÖmürBilgili Thank Omur! That's exactly what the problem is..! I set my Map's view property projection to "EPSG:4326" and left my overView to the default.

Answer (score 2):

So.. I figured out the problem, the **ol.control.overviewMap** has a ***view*** property as well, you will need to make sure the **ol.map** and the overviewMap has the same ***view*** property. In my case, I forgot to set the **ol.control.overviewMap**'s projection. My working sample code is shown below:

```
var mapView = new ol.View({
  projection: "EPSG:4326",
  center: [-97.5 , 50.5],
  zoom: 7
});
  var overviewView = new ol.View({projection:"EPSG:4326"});

  // Create scaleline control
  var scaleline = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

  var overview = new ol.control.OverviewMap
  ({
    view: overviewView
  });

  // create map interface 

  this.map = new ol.Map
  ({
      controls: [scaleline, overview],  //, attr
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults
      ({
          doubleClickZoom: false
      }),
      layers: [bing_layer],
      target: 'map',
    view: mapView
  });e
```